# how to build a 5 wall map in lejos-nxj with NXT brick

Tags: nxt, lejos-nxj

I have an NXT robot. 
I want to map a room without any obstacles, and "give" this map to the robot.
I have this sample code:

```
// Create a rudimentary map:
Line[] lines = new Line[3];
lines[0] = new Line(75f, 100f, 100f, 100f);
lines[1] = new Line(100, 100, 87, 75);
lines[2] = new Line(87, 75, 75, 100);
lejos.geom.Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(-50, -50, 250, 250); //(x,y,height,width)
LineMap myMap = new LineMap(lines, bounds); //create map
```

In this code, the lines create a triangle, that suppose to be an obstacle, and the bounds is the room walls.

The problem is that [`LineMap`](http://lejos.sourceforge.net/nxt/pc/api/lejos/robotics/mapping/LineMap.html) get lines and bounds, but the bounds is rectangle.
My type of room is without obstacles(so I don't need lines, or I can build a fake obstacle), and with 5 walls (Pentagon).

Does anyone know if there is any method that takes bounds of any kind and not just `Rectangle`s?
If I can give the robot the lines as walls and not as obstacles it would be great.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish a wall and an obstacle?

Comment: You right, I don't, I just make the obstacles as walls. Thanks